# Kinect thermal imaging

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can kinect sensor be used as a thermal imaging camera and return body temperature ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61076/kinect-thermal-imaging/) by [programme](https://answers.ros.org/users/4710/programme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-04-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, not that i know of. The Kinect IR sensor works with an IR wavelength not far away from visible light (830nm), which is too short for thermal imaging.

Also there may be a lot more reasons, why this isn't working, that i dont know of. :)

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2013-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-04-18**:
To test for yourself, turn off the lights, cover up the IR projector, point the kinect at something hot, and take a look at the IR image stream. @Ben_S is correct that you won't see anything (I've tried).

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-04-22**:
The human body has a wavelength around 10 micrometers. So compared to the bandwidth of the kinect, it's not even worth it trying :-)